# snmp - definition of a MIB

Tags: snmp

In SNMP, is the management information base (MIB):

1. A tree of information handled by an agent.
2. A set of objects definitions stored in a file

If the correct answer is the second one, how do you call the tree of information handled by an agent?

Comment: @Othman, just get the basics then move on to more important and valuable technologies.  SNMP is a bit of a dinosaur and, like XML/XSLT, is over complicated.  Don't get stuck on SNMP.   ...move on.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest definition is that an SNMP MIB is a database containing the managed objects which a device will expose to SNMP via an SNMP agent. The MIB appears, at least externally, to be a tree structure.

This is how [RFC 1156, Management Information Base for Network Management of TCP/IP-based internets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1156) defines it:

> Managed objects are accessed via a virtual information store, termed
> the Management Information Base or MIB.

Some people refer to the properties (values) of the managed objects as definitions of those objects. That would seem to be the source of your confusion.